# Facebook Login dialog issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I am opening Facebook login window in same window instead of popup window as per my requirement, but on cancel button click i'm facing problem with that like in
1. Chrome : it give warning 
o login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.c…:7!

Error shown in below attached image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should either:

1. Open the dialog in a popup window
2. Use the full redirect with `display=popup`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth#params

Comment: i know that but according my requirement i want to open in same window,twitter,linkedIn provider are working good.   Facebook should redirect to home page after cancel button click